# ChartJS Only Show Large Font Size for a Specific Tick

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am attempting to emphasize a specific value on the X-Axis if it meets a specific condition.

For example, in my [codepen](https://codepen.io/nuclearslug/pen/NJGmmy) I want to only change the font size of the 'blue' bar.  Is this even possible with Chart.js?

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    //only show large font size for 'Blue'
                    fontSize: 16
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Just by curiosity. Are you trying to highlight the largest value? If so, why not highlighting the whole bar? Let me know if you want to know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chartjs doesn't have a public api to do this but you can modify internal `_ticks` on [`beforeDraw`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) and make the label "Blue" as `major: true` then that label will be drawn using the [`major`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#tick-configuration) styling in tick configuration options.

Also use this with caution since it relies on internal implementation and thus might break in future releases (very unlikely to happen but just saying).

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    fontSize: 16,
                    major: {
                      fontSize: 20
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }, 
    plugins: [{
        beforeDraw: function({ chart }, options) {
            chart.boxes
            .find(box => box.id === "x-axis-0")
            ._ticks
            .find(tick => tick.label === "Blue")
            .major = true;
        }
    }]
});
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

PS: Just in case someone is wondering how I know this internal implementation I searched `fillText` in chartjs github source code and `console.log(myChart)` xD

Comment: If anyone runs into this and wonders why it doesn't work you need to enable major ticks. So you need to add enabled: true under the fontSize.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's not possible according to their docs. You can only do something like uppercase needed label with [callback](http://Looks%20like%20it's%20not%20possible%20according%20to%20their%20docs.%20You%20can%20only%20do%20something%20like%20uppercase%20needed%20label%20with) function

```
xAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    fontSize: 16,
    callback: v => v === 'Blue' ? v.toUpperCase() : v
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

For chartjs 3.0 and higher, it can be done by using [scriptable-options](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/general/options.html#scriptable-options). Include it like this into your options for ticks:

```
options: {
    scales: {
             x: {
                  ticks: {

font: {
       size: (c) => {
         if (c.index==1){
             return 20 // at tick label with idx one set fontsize 20
          }
          else {
            return 12 // for all other tick labels set fontsize 12
          }
}, 
},
},
},
},
},
```