# Chartjs ticks custome style

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

How can I change some style of `chartJs` ticks by condition?
For simplicity I removed condition that's no matter and work correct.
I want if condition is true the specific tick font size become 24 else 14 and I want to change its color.

```
...
xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              ...
              callback: function (value, index, values) {
                  if (true)
                    return {
                      fontSize: 24
                    };

                  return {
                    fontSize: 14
                  };
                }
            }
          }]
```

please, help me

Comment: Does the variables for what's going to go inside of the if come from the `class` or from `value, index, values` or both?

Comment: They come from `value, index, values` @AliF50

Comment: Do you think you can do something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54932374/chartjs-only-show-large-font-size-for-a-specific-tick